# Coordinate transform

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, coordinate-systems

Can anyone see what transformation $$r\to f(r)$$ transforms $$\exp(2\phi(r))(dr^2+r^2d\theta^2)$$ to
$$df^2+\sinh^2(f)d\theta^2$$?
I there a systematic way to attack such a problem -- rather than just hoping that  I somehow spot it?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are working with some $2$-manifold $M$, I believe you just have to write down a general transformation $\psi : M \to M$, and then write down the pullback of $2$-tensors. After that you pull the metric back and equate things finding what your transformation must satisfy. I don't know if that's the procedure, but that's what came on my mind.

Comment: Do we perhaps know more about $\phi$?

Comment: @Berci: Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $\phi$ can't be very creative. Since the curvature of this surface must be invariant under the change of coordinates, with a bit of computation we'll get (from the latter) $K=-1$ and (from the former) $K=-e^{-2\phi(r)}\big(\phi''(r)+\frac1r\phi'(r)\big)$. Thus, $\phi$ must satisfy the ODE
$$\phi''(r)+\frac1r\phi'(r)=e^{2\phi(r)}\,.\tag{$\star$}$$
(This should look somewhat familiar if you've computed curvature of a conformally flat metric before.)
It also makes us think we're looking at some hyperbolic metric, of course.

Starting at the other end of the problem, you need 
\begin{align*} f'(r) &= e^{\phi(r)} \\
\sinh f(r) &= re^{\phi(r)}\,,
\end{align*}
and we can actually integrate patiently to obtain
$$\cosh f(r) = \frac{Cr^2+1}{Cr^2-1}\,,$$
so $$f(r) = \log\left(\frac{(Cr+1)^2}{Cr^2-1}\right)\,.$$
Amazingly, if we now set $\phi(r) = \log f'(r)$, we do in fact (!) get a solution of the ODE ($\star$) above.